# Recycler view inside Recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have multiple vertical recycler views inside a main recycler view.

The issue I am facing is that for the inner recycler view all the inner views are getting instantiated at once.

I tired solutions like using a common view pool https://proandroiddev.com/optimizing-nested-recyclerview-a9b7830a4ba7

and also followed other stackoverflow answers. The recommendation is to not use a recycler view inside other recycler views

But if this is not avoidable any suggestions on how to proceed ?

I would like the inner recycler view to load fast and the items to be loaded only when the user scrolls.

Comment: I have worked with multi level `Recyclerview` never face this issue. if your data is less then it load at once but if you data is more then it will load data one by one just like Single `recyclerview`

Comment: If you use nested recyclerview you can face many different problems. If you decide not using nested recyclerview, I can help you how to implement nested list in android.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this class for the header, content and footer in the one recyclerview only.

Below is the solution.

```
public abstract class BaseDataRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_MAX_COUNT = 1000;
    private static final int HEADER_VIEW_TYPE_OFFSET = 0;
    private static final int FOOTER_VIEW_TYPE_OFFSET = HEADER_VIEW_TYPE_OFFSET + VIEW_TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    private static final int CONTENT_VIEW_TYPE_OFFSET = FOOTER_VIEW_TYPE_OFFSET + VIEW_TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    private int headerItemCount;
    private int contentItemCount;
    private int footerItemCount;
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public final RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Delegate to proper methods based on the viewType ranges.
        if (viewType >= HEADER_VIEW_TYPE_OFFSET && viewType < HEADER_VIEW_TYPE_OFFSET + VIEW_TYPE_MAX_COUNT) {
            return onCreateHeaderItemViewHolder(parent, viewType - HEADER_VIEW_TYPE_OFFSET);
        } else if (viewType >= FOOTER_VIEW_TYPE_OFFSET && viewType < FOOTER_VIEW_TYPE_OFFSET + VIEW_TYPE_MAX_COUNT) {
            return onCreateFooterItemViewHolder(parent, viewType - FOOTER_VIEW_TYPE_OFFSET);
        } else if (viewType >= CONTENT_VIEW_TYPE_OFFSET && viewType < CONTENT_VIEW_TYPE_OFFSET + VIEW_TYPE_MAX_COUNT) {
            return onCreateContentItemViewHolder(parent, viewType - CONTENT_VIEW_TYPE_OFFSET);
        } else {
            // This shouldn't happen as we check that the viewType provided by the client is valid.
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public final void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        // Delegate to proper methods based on the viewType ranges.
        if (headerItemCount > 0 && position < headerItemCount) {
            onBindHeaderItemViewHolder(viewHolder, position);
        } else if (contentItemCount > 0 && position - headerItemCount < contentItemCount) {
            onBindContentItemViewHolder(viewHolder, position - headerItemCount);
        } else {
            onBindFooterItemViewHolder(viewHolder, position - headerItemCount - contentItemCount);
        }
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public final int getItemCount() {
        // Cache the counts and return the sum of them.
        headerItemCount = getHeaderItemCount();
        contentItemCount = getContentItemCount();
        footerItemCount = getFooterItemCount();
        return headerItemCount + contentItemCount + footerItemCount;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public final int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Delegate to proper methods based on the position, but validate first.
        if (headerItemCount > 0 && position < headerItemCount) {
            return validateViewType(getHeaderItemViewType(position)) + HEADER_VIEW_TYPE_OFFSET;
        } else if (contentItemCount > 0 && position - headerItemCount < contentItemCount) {
            return validateViewType(getContentItemViewType(position - headerItemCount)) + CONTENT_VIEW_TYPE_OFFSET;
        } else {
            return validateViewType(getFooterItemViewType(position - headerItemCount - contentItemCount)) + FOOTER_VIEW_TYPE_OFFSET;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Validates that the view type is within the valid range.
     *
     * @param viewType the view type.
     * @return the given view type.
     */
    private int validateViewType(int viewType) {
        if (viewType < 0 || viewType >= VIEW_TYPE_MAX_COUNT) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("viewType must be between 0 and " + VIEW_TYPE_MAX_COUNT);
        }
        return viewType;
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that a header item is inserted.
     *
     * @param position the position of the header item.
     */
    public final void notifyHeaderItemInserted(int position) {
        int newHeaderItemCount = getHeaderItemCount();
        if (position < 0 || position >= newHeaderItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given position " + position + " is not within the position bounds for header items [0 - " + (newHeaderItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that multiple header items are inserted.
     *
     * @param positionStart the position.
     * @param itemCount     the item count.
     */
    public final void notifyHeaderItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        int newHeaderItemCount = getHeaderItemCount();
        if (positionStart < 0 || itemCount < 0 || positionStart + itemCount > newHeaderItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given range [" + positionStart + " - " + (positionStart + itemCount - 1) + "] is not within the position bounds for header items [0 - " + (newHeaderItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that a header item is changed.
     *
     * @param position the position.
     */
    public final void notifyHeaderItemChanged(int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position >= headerItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given position " + position + " is not within the position bounds for header items [0 - " + (headerItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that multiple header items are changed.
     *
     * @param positionStart the position.
     * @param itemCount     the item count.
     */
    public final void notifyHeaderItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        if (positionStart < 0 || itemCount < 0 || positionStart + itemCount >= headerItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given range [" + positionStart + " - " + (positionStart + itemCount - 1) + "] is not within the position bounds for header items [0 - " + (headerItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that an existing header item is moved to another position.
     *
     * @param fromPosition the original position.
     * @param toPosition   the new position.
     */
    public void notifyHeaderItemMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        if (fromPosition < 0 || toPosition < 0 || fromPosition >= headerItemCount || toPosition >= headerItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given fromPosition " + fromPosition + " or toPosition " + toPosition + " is not within the position bounds for header items [0 - " + (headerItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that a header item is removed.
     *
     * @param position the position.
     */
    public void notifyHeaderItemRemoved(int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position >= headerItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given position " + position + " is not within the position bounds for header items [0 - " + (headerItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that multiple header items are removed.
     *
     * @param positionStart the position.
     * @param itemCount     the item count.
     */
    public void notifyHeaderItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        if (positionStart < 0 || itemCount < 0 || positionStart + itemCount > headerItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given range [" + positionStart + " - " + (positionStart + itemCount - 1) + "] is not within the position bounds for header items [0 - " + (headerItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that a content item is inserted.
     *
     * @param position the position of the content item.
     */
    public final void notifyContentItemInserted(int position) {
        int newHeaderItemCount = getHeaderItemCount();
        int newContentItemCount = getContentItemCount();
        if (position < 0 || position >= newContentItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given position " + position + " is not within the position bounds for content items [0 - " + (newContentItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemInserted(position + newHeaderItemCount);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that multiple content items are inserted.
     *
     * @param positionStart the position.
     * @param itemCount     the item count.
     */
    public final void notifyContentItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        int newHeaderItemCount = getHeaderItemCount();
        int newContentItemCount = getContentItemCount();
        if (positionStart < 0 || itemCount < 0 || positionStart + itemCount > newContentItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given range [" + positionStart + " - " + (positionStart + itemCount - 1) + "] is not within the position bounds for content items [0 - " + (newContentItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart + newHeaderItemCount, itemCount);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that a content item is changed.
     *
     * @param position the position.
     */
    public final void notifyContentItemChanged(int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position >= contentItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given position " + position + " is not within the position bounds for content items [0 - " + (contentItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemChanged(position + headerItemCount);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that multiple content items are changed.
     *
     * @param positionStart the position.
     * @param itemCount     the item count.
     */
    public final void notifyContentItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        if (positionStart < 0 || itemCount < 0 || positionStart + itemCount > contentItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given range [" + positionStart + " - " + (positionStart + itemCount - 1) + "] is not within the position bounds for content items [0 - " + (contentItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemRangeChanged(positionStart + headerItemCount, itemCount);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that an existing content item is moved to another position.
     *
     * @param fromPosition the original position.
     * @param toPosition   the new position.
     */
    public final void notifyContentItemMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        if (fromPosition < 0 || toPosition < 0 || fromPosition >= contentItemCount || toPosition >= contentItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given fromPosition " + fromPosition + " or toPosition " + toPosition + " is not within the position bounds for content items [0 - " + (contentItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition + headerItemCount, toPosition + headerItemCount);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that a content item is removed.
     *
     * @param position the position.
     */
    public final void notifyContentItemRemoved(int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position >= contentItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given position " + position + " is not within the position bounds for content items [0 - " + (contentItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemRemoved(position + headerItemCount);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that multiple content items are removed.
     *
     * @param positionStart the position.
     * @param itemCount     the item count.
     */
    public final void notifyContentItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        if (positionStart < 0 || itemCount < 0 || positionStart + itemCount > contentItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given range [" + positionStart + " - " + (positionStart + itemCount - 1) + "] is not within the position bounds for content items [0 - " + (contentItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(positionStart + headerItemCount, itemCount);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that a footer item is inserted.
     *
     * @param position the position of the content item.
     */
    public final void notifyFooterItemInserted(int position) {
        int newHeaderItemCount = getHeaderItemCount();
        int newContentItemCount = getContentItemCount();
        int newFooterItemCount = getFooterItemCount();
        if (position < 0 || position >= newFooterItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given position " + position + " is not within the position bounds for footer items [0 - " + (newFooterItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemInserted(position + newHeaderItemCount + newContentItemCount);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that multiple footer items are inserted.
     *
     * @param positionStart the position.
     * @param itemCount     the item count.
     */
    public final void notifyFooterItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        int newHeaderItemCount = getHeaderItemCount();
        int newContentItemCount = getContentItemCount();
        int newFooterItemCount = getFooterItemCount();
        if (positionStart < 0 || itemCount < 0 || positionStart + itemCount > newFooterItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given range [" + positionStart + " - " + (positionStart + itemCount - 1) + "] is not within the position bounds for footer items [0 - " + (newFooterItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart + newHeaderItemCount + newContentItemCount, itemCount);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that a footer item is changed.
     *
     * @param position the position.
     */
    public final void notifyFooterItemChanged(int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position >= footerItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given position " + position + " is not within the position bounds for footer items [0 - " + (footerItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemChanged(position + headerItemCount + contentItemCount);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that multiple footer items are changed.
     *
     * @param positionStart the position.
     * @param itemCount     the item count.
     */
    public final void notifyFooterItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        if (positionStart < 0 || itemCount < 0 || positionStart + itemCount > footerItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given range [" + positionStart + " - " + (positionStart + itemCount - 1) + "] is not within the position bounds for footer items [0 - " + (footerItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemRangeChanged(positionStart + headerItemCount + contentItemCount, itemCount);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that an existing footer item is moved to another position.
     *
     * @param fromPosition the original position.
     * @param toPosition   the new position.
     */
    public final void notifyFooterItemMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        if (fromPosition < 0 || toPosition < 0 || fromPosition >= footerItemCount || toPosition >= footerItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given fromPosition " + fromPosition + " or toPosition " + toPosition + " is not within the position bounds for footer items [0 - " + (footerItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition + headerItemCount + contentItemCount, toPosition + headerItemCount + contentItemCount);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that a footer item is removed.
     *
     * @param position the position.
     */
    public final void notifyFooterItemRemoved(int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position >= footerItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given position " + position + " is not within the position bounds for footer items [0 - " + (footerItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemRemoved(position + headerItemCount + contentItemCount);
    }
    /**
     * Notifies that multiple footer items are removed.
     *
     * @param positionStart the position.
     * @param itemCount     the item count.
     */
    public final void notifyFooterItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        if (positionStart < 0 || itemCount < 0 || positionStart + itemCount > footerItemCount) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The given range [" + positionStart + " - " + (positionStart + itemCount - 1) + "] is not within the position bounds for footer items [0 - " + (footerItemCount - 1) + "].");
        }
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(positionStart + headerItemCount + contentItemCount, itemCount);
    }
    /**
     * Gets the header item view type. By default, this method returns 0.
     *
     * @param position the position.
     * @return the header item view type (within the range [0 - VIEW_TYPE_MAX_COUNT-1]).
     */
    protected int getHeaderItemViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the footer item view type. By default, this method returns 0.
     *
     * @param position the position.
     * @return the footer item view type (within the range [0 - VIEW_TYPE_MAX_COUNT-1]).
     */
    protected int getFooterItemViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the content item view type. By default, this method returns 0.
     *
     * @param position the position.
     * @return the content item view type (within the range [0 - VIEW_TYPE_MAX_COUNT-1]).
     */
    protected int getContentItemViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    /**
     * Gets the header item count. This method can be called several times, so it should not
     * calculate the count every time.
     *
     * @return the header item count.
     */
    protected abstract int getHeaderItemCount();
    /**
     * Gets the footer item count. This method can be called several times, so it should not
     * calculate the count every time.
     *
     * @return the footer item count.
     */
    protected abstract int getFooterItemCount();
    /**
     * Gets the content item count. This method can be called several times, so it should not
     * calculate the count every time.
     *
     * @return the content item count.
     */
    protected abstract int getContentItemCount();
    /**
     * This method works exactly the same as {@link #onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup,
     * int)}, but for header items.
     *
     * @param parent         the parent view.
     * @param headerViewType the view type for the header.
     * @return the view holder.
     */
    protected abstract RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateHeaderItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int headerViewType);
    /**
     * This method works exactly the same as {@link #onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup,
     * int)}, but for footer items.
     *
     * @param parent         the parent view.
     * @param footerViewType the view type for the footer.
     * @return the view holder.
     */
    protected abstract RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateFooterItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int footerViewType);
    /**
     * This method works exactly the same as {@link #onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup,
     * int)}, but for content items.
     *
     * @param parent          the parent view.
     * @param contentViewType the view type for the content.
     * @return the view holder.
     */
    protected abstract RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateContentItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int contentViewType);
    /**
     * This method works exactly the same as {@link #onBindViewHolder(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
     * int)}, but for header items.
     *
     * @param headerViewHolder the view holder for the header item.
     * @param position         the position.
     */
    protected abstract void onBindHeaderItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder headerViewHolder, int position);
    /**
     * This method works exactly the same as {@link #onBindViewHolder(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
     * int)}, but for footer items.
     *
     * @param footerViewHolder the view holder for the footer item.
     * @param position         the position.
     */
    protected abstract void onBindFooterItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder footerViewHolder, int position);
    /**
     * This method works exactly the same as {@link #onBindViewHolder(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
     * int)}, but for content items.
     *
     * @param contentViewHolder the view holder for the content item.
     * @param position          the position.
     */
    protected abstract void onBindContentItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder contentViewHolder, int position);
}
```

And you call this class like this.

public class YourAdapter extends BaseDataRecyclerViewAdapter {

```
private Context mContext;


public YourAdapter(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;

}

@Override
protected int getHeaderItemCount() {
    return headerList.size();
}

@Override
protected int getFooterItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
protected int getContentItemCount() {
    return contentList.size();
}

@Override
protected RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateHeaderItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int headerViewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_header, parent, false);
    return new ParentHeaderViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
protected RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateFooterItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int footerViewType) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateContentItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int contentViewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_content, parent, false);
    return new ParentContentViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
protected void onBindHeaderItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder headerViewHolder, int position) {
    ParentHeaderViewHolder viewHolder = (ParentHeaderViewHolder) headerViewHolder;
    viewHolder.bindData();

}

@Override
protected void onBindFooterItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder footerViewHolder, int position) {

}

@Override
protected void onBindContentItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder contentViewHolder, int position) {
    ParentContentViewHolder viewHolder = (ParentContentViewHolder) contentViewHolder;
    viewHolder.bindData(activity, position);
}

public class ParentHeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {



    public ParentHeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    public void bindData() {

    }
}



public class ParentContentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ParentContentViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);



    }

    public void bindData(final Activity activity, int position) {
    }

}
```

}

Hope this will help